# New iPhone battery draining so fast

Tags: iphone, ios, battery

Today I got a brand new iPhone 12. I noticed the battery keeps dropping by 5% every hour when the phone is IDLE.

From the box the battery was at 55% I guess. Now, after 5 hours the phone is at 25% without doing anything special.

I connected to Wi-Fi, downloaded 4 apps that I use daily and set up my accounts for like 30 minutes.

The phone wasn't connected to Wi-Fi since then and Cellular connection is Off for approximately the last 4 hours. I tried turning off some background app refresh and I did some other stuff that I found on Youtube.

Then, I checked the batteryCycleCount from the log in Analytics log and It shows `<integer> -1 <integer>` .

Is `-1` logic ? I didn't charge the phone yet.

The phone came with iOS 15.4.1

Is anyone having the same issue? Is it normal? This is first time with iPhone, I was used to Android and this is the first time I'm having issues with battery after getting a brand new phone.

Comment: I would recommend charging it to 100% and then use it and see if its still draining a lot. When I got a new iPhone I noticed it was draining a lot but after I charged it to 100% for the first time I noticed it stopped draining as fast. Now the battery life feels a lot longer. Some people say this method doesn't apply to modern phones but I feel like it made a difference to my phone so I recommend it

Comment: @mpp : Thank you that solves the issue. I'm still at 95% at the end of my work day.